# Struts 2 jquery grid plugin set summaryType

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

The strust 2 jquery grid plugin does not support `summaryType` for columns, as a work around I try to set it as:

```
$("#gridtable").jqGrid('setColProp', 'amount',{summaryType:'sum'});
```

This does not work at the first time. But after reloading the grid, or sorting some columns, the summary is displayed.

It seems that the `summaryType` needs to be defined before grid is constructed. I try to call `setColProp` in `onBeforeTopics` but it didn't worked again.

So is there any way I set column property before grid constructed ?!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid will be used internally? You can examine the comment at the beginning of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` line (or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or `grid.base.js`)

Comment: The jgGrid version is 4.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that strust 2 jquery grid plugin uses some old jqGrid in version 4.6/4.7. Starting with version 4.4.4 jqGrid supports `onInitGrid` callback and `jqGridInitGrid` event which could be very helpful in your case. The callback/event will be called/triggered after the outer elements of jqGrid will be build (column headers for example), but **before** the first filling of the grid with data (before the first call of internal `populate` method).

Thus you can use the following code for the required changes:

```
$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridInitGrid", function (e) {
    $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", "amount", { summaryType: "sum" }); 
});
```

It's important to understand that you can/should make the binding **before** creating the grid because the empty `<table id="gridtable"></table>` already exist and the binding will be not changed during creating jqGrid.

[Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) has another callback `beforeInitGrid` and the corresponding event `jqGridBeforeInitGrid`, which will be called earlier, before any outer parts of jqGrid will be created, but the `jqGridInitGrid` event would be enough for your purpose already.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a day